# WPF Listbox binding: SelectedItem not setting

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

I have a ListBox simplified to the following XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
     SelectedItem="SelectedProperty" />
```

and in my ViewModel:

```
private List<Property> propertyList;
private Property selectedProperty;
public List<Property> Properties 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return propertyList; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        propertyList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Properties");
    } 
}
public Property SelectedProperty
{
    get
    {
        return selectedProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProperty");
        selectedProperty= value;
    }
}
```

My List box populates fine, but no matter what I try I cannot seem to get the SelectedProperty to update when I select an item in my list box. I have tried switching it all around to use `ObservableCollection` rather than `List` and adding an Event handler for CollectionChanged, but this has not worked.

I am sure I am missing something stupid, and cannot see the wood for the trees. I am reaching the end of my tether and need someone to step in and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to bind to the `SelectedProperty`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" 
 DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty}"  />
```

Comment: Knew it would be something obvious. Thanks.